# Extracting a Phrase from a line

Tags: c, string

I'm looking for a word/phrase in a file.txt.

file looks like this:

```
    apple tree '\t' data
    apple '\t' data
    apple pie '\t' data
    Greek '\t' data
    Holland ; Netherlands ; The Netherlands '\t' data
```

I am looking for a `char *word` inside this huge file. It gets tricky when I have words like `Netherlands` or `The Netherlands` and I want to grab that data.

I have broken the problem down into tiny parts. So far I know how many lines the file has and can use that information to fseek to that line. Those parts work independently of this part below.

```
file_lines = 12325;

// line_index[] every element corresponds to a line in to a line in the file.
char* buffer[256];
FILE fp = fopen(file.txt, "r") 

int i, j, k;
for(i = line_index[index_start]; i < line_index[index_end]; i++)
{
   fseek(fp, i, SEEK_SET);
   fgets(buffer, 256, fp);

   if(strstr(buffer, word) != NULL) // word is here
   {
     // having problems finding the word here

     for(j = 0; j < 256; j++)
       for(k = 0; k < 256; k++)
       {  
         if(buffer[k] == word[k])
          continue;

         if(buffer[k] == ' ')
          continue;

         if(buffer[k] == ';')
          break;

         if(buffer[k] == '\t')
           break;
       }

   }
}
```

My biggest problem is making sure the word/phrase is in that line. I can know which potential line has an instance of the word, but if I am looking for apple I might get apple tree if I don't search inside that line correctly.

Please help.

Comment: You know that strstr() returns you a pointer to the word in the buffer, right? Maybe using that return value would help.

Comment: The result of strstr() minus the buffer's address is the index. Pointer arithmetics...

Comment: It gives you a pointer into the buffer.

Comment: If you are trying to return "data", after you get a match search in the buffer for a tab \t and then the data is just after that.

Comment: So if I was looking for `apple` I would find `apple tree`. Then I would return apple tree's data instead of apple's data.

Comment: Ok, instead of strstr look at strtok() and use '\t' and ';' as delimiters.

Comment: What Charlie says, but it seems you don't want to scan after the tab anyway. Before `strtok`, find the tab and change it to a 0. Then use `strtok` and a `strcmp` on each of the returned substrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly...

```
   char *tab = strchr(buffer, '\t');
   if(tab) *tab = 0;
   if(strstr(buffer, word) != NULL) // word is here
   {
       char *token = strtok(buffer, ";");
       int found = 0;
       while(token) {
          // remove this printf later, but for now it will help you debug
          printf("'%s' vs '%s'\n", word, token); 
          if(strcmp(word, token) == 0) {
              found = 1;
              break;
          }
          token = strtok(0, ";");
       }
       if(found) {
           if(tab == 0) {
              printf("No data for %s\n", word);
           } else {
              printf("data is '%s'\n", tab+1);
           }
       }
```

Comment: It is really good, but it doesn't work when the database has something like `a red apple` it will grab the data from that instance instead of `apple`.

Comment: So word is "apple" ? If the line is "a red apple \t data" the strstr will match but the strtok() -> strcmp should not match because strtok should only return 'a red apple' not 'red'.

Comment: Yeah you are right, it is only doing it for one of the entries so it is something else.